# What does "get Bream clean" mean?

Tags: meaning

The following quote is taken from a [writing assignment](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/summit/downloads/summit1/UNIT_07_P84_Writing.pdf):

> Wanna get clean? ***Get Bream clean***!

What does "*get Bream clean*" mean?

Comment: In that case, "Bream" is a brand of soap that the manufacturers claim gets things clean in a way that ordinary soaps can't.  Because of advertising restrictions they can't really say it works better than other soaps, so they turn their brand name into an adjective- it's not just clean, it's "Bream clean".  It's just an advertising slogan.

Comment: Interesting! So _get_ means _become_ in this context, right?

Comment: Yes, or *obtain* as in *obtain a result*

Comment: I'd like to put a check mark next to your comment, but since it's a comment, not an answer, the forum doesn't let me do it. Thank you so much, anyway! :)

Comment: @Jim That's the answer. Post it - claim your kewpie doll!

Comment: Where did you see this in a soap ad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bream", in this case, is a brand of soap that the manufacturers claim gets things clean in a way that ordinary soaps can't. Because of advertising restrictions they can't really say it works better than other soaps, so they turn their brand name into an adjective- it's not just clean, it's "Bream clean". It's just an advertising slogan.

Comment: No doubt "Bream" is a brand name, and the phrase is from an ad slogan. But where do they make this stuff? When I searched for `"get Bream clean"` on Google, I got only [8 hits](http://www.google.com/#q=%22get+Bream+clean%22&safe=off) (and one of those was to this page). The rest were linked to an [English test](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/summit/downloads/summit1/UNIT_07_P84_Writing.pdf). Is this even a real brand?

Comment: @J.R. Actually I saw it in an English book called _Top Notch_ and couldn't understand the meaning. That's when I decided to put my question here. But the text is exactly the same as the one you have seen in that English test.

Comment: @Behad - If you saw it in an English book, then why does your question say that you saw it in a soap ad?